# return a property of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, compiler-errors

I have `vatGroupTotals` as an object

```
{ vatRate: 22,
 vatGroupNetTotal: 3000,
 vatGroupVatTotal: 660,
 vatGroupGrossTotal: 3660 }
```

and I see that whenever I am asking to render `vatGroupTotals.vatGroupVatTotals` there is an error that I am missing `:`. Any one have an idea?

```
let vatGroupTotals = CalculateVatGroupTotalFromLinesTotal(lines);
let vatGroupVatTotalFromGrandTotal = CalculateVatGroupTotalFromNetTotal(
    vatGroupTotals.vatRate,
    vatGroupTotals.vatGroupNetTotal , vatGroupTotals.vatGroupVatTotal);

return {vatGroupTotals.vatGroupVatTotal,vatGroupVatTotalFromGrandTotal};
```

Comment: You can't use the auto-naming feature of object literals with properties. For those properties, as the answers have told you, you must provide a name.

Answer (score 0):

Can you convert your return to non es6 format and see if that works?  {A:A,B:B}

Comment: return {vatGroupTotals, vatGroupVatTotalFromGrandTotal}; actuullay it works if i dont precise the property

Comment: return {vatGroupTotals ,vatGroupVatTotalFromGrandTotal};
this one works ..that means when i dont precise the property

Answer (score 0):

You returned this function as an object.
An object has to have an property name

```
function test(){
    let vatGroupTotals = { vatRate: 22, vatGroupNetTotal: 3000, vatGroupVatTotal: 660, vatGroupGrossTotal: 3660 };
    return {name: vatGroupTotals.vatGroupVatTotal}; //added here an property name
}
console.log(test());
```

Comment: i could render without putting name : , if i dont precise the property